# Node.js child process exits with SIGTERM

Tags: node.js, linux, child-process

I'm spawning a child process using Node 6.9.

```
const child = require('child_process').execFile('command', args); 
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('child:', data);
});
child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('child:', data);
});
child.on('close', (code, signal) => {
    console.log(`ERROR: child terminated. Exit code: ${code}, signal: ${signal}`);
});
```

My child process runs for ~1m 30s but then I get this output from my Node.js program:

```
ERROR: child terminated. Exit code: null, signal: SIGTERM
```

What terminates my child process and why?

**Edit:**
I've added killSignal: 'SIGILL' as an option.

```
var child = require('child_process').execFile('geth', args, { killSignal: 'SIGILL'});
```

Now, I get this:

```
ERROR: go-ethereum terminated. Exit code: 2, signal: null
```

Comment: Does “standalone” mean inside the container but not spawned by Node, or outside the container but spawned by Node?

Comment: Hi Ryan, sorry I made it more clear. Inside the container but not spawned by Node

Comment: I don’t suppose `args` has a `timeout` property? If you pass `Object.assign({}, args, {killSignal: 'SIGILL'})`, does the signal change?

Comment: I now get ERROR: go-ethereum terminated. Exit code: 2, signal: null. See above.

Answer (score 12):

I found the problem and a solution.

From https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback

> maxBuffer  largest amount of data (in bytes) allowed on stdout or stderr - if exceeded child process is killed (Default: 200*1024)

I can set the `maxBuffer` option higher.

```
childProcess.execFile('geth', args, { maxBuffer:  400 * 1024});
```

It seems you can't disable the `maxBuffer` option, not even by setting it to 0. But it seems to be on purpose.

Comment: I think the same thing happened to me when I ran a program with "progress notifications" as a subprocess.  After running for a while, Node keeled.  It seems tricky to estimate how big the buffer size should be.  It seems to me that a good general solution is to avoid running programs that log too much information.

Comment: Yeah, it helps. But better use the more appropriate function – `spawn` (instead of `execFile`). See: https://medium.com/edge-coders/-e69498fe970a