# Child process exiting with SIGTERM (possibly due to exceeding maxBuffer); how can I confirm that it's a buffer problem and fix it?

Tags: node.js, child-process

### Issue

My child process is exiting after about 30 minutes with `SIGTERM` and no other debug output. Given the information on [Node.js child process exits with SIGTERM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43401872/node-js-child-process-exits-with-sigterm), I think it's reasonably likely that the process is exiting due to exceeding its `maxBuffer`, as the uptime is non-deterministic and indeed is improved by increasing the `maxBuffer`. With the default 205 KB of `maxBuffer`, it consistently runs for 1-3 minutes; and with 10 MB, it consistently runs for 30-60 minutes.

### Aim

The child process is producing a stream of text at an average rate of about 1 MB every 10 minutes (1.66 KB per second).

The log entries in the text stream are multi-line (see sample below of the lines that make up one log entry), so I am using Node to parse them line-by-line to extract the information of interest (from `*   << Request  >>` to `-   End`   ):

```
*   << Request  >> 113214123 
-   Begin          req 113214077 rxreq
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /ping
-   RespStatus     200
-   End
```

### Code

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const { createInterface } = require('readline');

const cp = exec("tail -F 2021-02-25.log", { maxBuffer: 10000000 });

createInterface(cp.stdout, cp.stdin)
.on('line', line => {
    // ...
    // (Implementation not shown, as it's hundreds of lines long):
    // Add the line to our line-buffer, and if we've reached "-   End   " yet, parse
    // those lines into a corresponding JS object and clear the line-buffer, ready
    // to receive another line.
    // ...
});

cp.on('close', (code, signal) => {
    console.error(`Child process exiting unexpectedly. Code: ${code}; signal: ${signal}.`);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

### Question

Essentially, "how can I avoid getting the `SIGTERM`" – but more specifically:

- How can I confirm that the `SIGTERM` is really received due to the child process exceeding the buffer? Is there a way, for example, to inspect the buffer usage of a child process while it's running?
- Is the buffer perhaps getting overloaded due to Node spending too long executing the line-parsing function? Is there a way to monitor this?
- Am I missing an extra aspect that I need to do, such as manually flushing some buffer?

I think throwing extra buffer at the problem is the wrong way to solve it; 10 MB already seems pretty excessive, and I need to be able to guarantee indefinite uptime (rather than increasing buffer a little more each time it fails).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to diagnose that the child process exited due to exceeding its buffer

I searched the Node.js codebase's tests for mentions of `maxBuffer` and found one that shows [how to diagnose](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/30fb4a015db2226aabaed457ec8930c9f9b8fd78/test/parallel/test-child-process-exec-maxbuf.js#L20) that a child process exited due to exceeding its allotted `maxBuffer`, which I'll copy out here:

```js
// One of the tests from the Node.js codebase:
{
  const cmd =
    `"${process.execPath}" -e "console.log('a'.repeat(1024 * 1024))"`;

  cp.exec(cmd, common.mustCall((err) => {
    assert(err instanceof RangeError);
    assert.strictEqual(err.message, 'stdout maxBuffer length exceeded');
    assert.strictEqual(err.code, 'ERR_CHILD_PROCESS_STDIO_MAXBUFFER');
  }));
}
```

So I incorporated an equivalent diagnostic function into my app:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const { createInterface } = require('readline');

/**
 * This termination callback is distinct to listening for the "error" event
 * (which does not fire at all, in the case of buffer overflow).
 * @see https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_error
 * @see https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback
 * @param {import("child_process").ExecException | null} error 
 * @param {string} stdout
 * @param {string} stderr 
 * @type {import("child_process").SpawnOptions}
 */
function terminationCallback(error, stdout, stderr){
    if(error === null){
        // Healthy termination. We'll get an exit code and signal from
        // the "close" event handler instead, so will just defer to those
        // logs for debug.
        return;
    }
    console.log(
        `[error] Child process got error with code ${error.code}.` + 
        ` instanceof RangeError: ${error instanceof RangeError}.` +
        ` Error message was: ${error.message}`
    );
    console.log(`stderr (length ${stderr.length}):\n${stderr}`);
    console.log(`stdout (length ${stdout.length}):\n${stdout}`);
}

const cp = exec(
    "tail -F 2021-02-25.log",
    { maxBuffer: 10000000 },
    terminationCallback
);

createInterface(cp.stdout, cp.stdin)
.on('line', line => {
    // ...
    // Implementation not shown
    // ...
});

cp.on('close', (code, signal) => {
    console.error(
        `Child process exiting unexpectedly. ` + 
        `Code: ${code}; signal: ${signal}.`
    );
    process.exit(1);
});
```

When I ran my app for a few minutes, indeed, I found that this termination callback was called, and that it satisfied all the assertions expected in the Node.js test for a child process that had exited due to exceeding its buffer.

I also noticed that the `stdout` returned in that termination callback was exactly 1000000 characters long – this matched exactly with the number of bytes that I'd set as the `maxBuffer`. It was at this point that I came to understand the difference between `require("child_process").exec()` and `require("child_process").spawn()`.

### How to make a child process that can safely stream any amount of data from `stdout`

[exec()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) and [spawn()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) have overlapping functionality, but ultimately are suited for different purposes, which is not really spelled out in the [Child Process documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options). The clue is in the construction arguments that they accept.

- `exec()` accepts a termination callback, and its options support `maxBuffer` (but not [stdio](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio)).
- `spawn()` doesn't accept a termination callback, and its options support `stdio` (but not `maxBuffer`).

The headline here is that:

- **`exec()` is suited for tasks that have a definite end** (upon which you'd harvest the `stdout`/`stderr` that the child process has been accumulating into its buffer the whole time it has been working).
- **`spawn()` is suited for tasks that may run indefinitely**, as you can configure where the `stdout`/`stderr`/`stdin` streams get piped off to. The default configuration for `options.stdio`, `"pipe"`, which pipes them to the parent process (your Node.js app), is appropriate in our example where we need to establish a `readline` interface and consume the `stdout` line-by-line. There is no explicit buffer limit other than that imposed by the operating system itself (which should be quite generous!).

So, if you're ever writing a Node.js app that manages a child process tasked with anything that runs indefinitely:

- watching logs (e.g. `tail -F 2021-02-25.log`) non-stop and parsing them
- running an always-on live streaming service (e.g. `ffmpeg <some complex args here>`)

... you should be using `spawn()`!

Conversely, for tasks with a definite end and a predictable, reasonable buffer size (e.g. `mkdir -vp some/dir/path` or `rsync --verbose <src> <dest>`), then you can go ahead and use `exec()`!

There may of course be other distinctions between the two, but this aspect of stream handling is really impactful.

#### How to rewrite using `spawn()`

Just two lines needs changing (and one of them is merely the import statement)! Note that the default `options.stdio` value of `"pipe"` is appropriate here, so we don't even need to pass in an options object.

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const { createInterface } = require('readline');

const cp = spawn("tail", ["-F", "2021-02-25.log"]);

createInterface(cp.stdout, cp.stdin)
.on('line', line => {
    // ...
    // (Implementation not shown, as it's hundreds of lines long):
    // Add the line to our line-buffer, and if we've reached "-   End   " yet, parse
    // those lines into a corresponding JS object and clear the line-buffer, ready
    // to receive another line.
    // ...
});

cp.on('close', (code, signal) => {
    console.error(`Child process exiting unexpectedly. Code: ${code}; signal: ${signal}.`);
    process.exit(1);
});
```